# Proving indecomposability of special modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

I'm reading the following paper: http://math0.bnu.edu.cn/~huwei/paper/Holm-Hu-1.pdf

On page 795 and 796 there are the definitions (in a diagrammatical way) of some $A_n$ modules, whereupon $A_n:=k[x,y]/\langle x^2,xy^{n+1},y^{n+2}\rangle$.

All the $A_n$ modules defined there should be indecomposable.

> > **Question:** Is there an easy way to prove this?

Of course, one could show that the endomorphism ring is local, but that seems to end in a lot of extensive computations.

Can we use anyhow that $A_n$ is local and commutative, or the fact that $x$ and $y$ are nilpotent?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the best approach is staring at the module and convincing yourself it can't be written non-trivially as a direct sum.  

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello.

I believe that the endmorphism ring may not be hard to compute in this case.

Let $R = k[x,y]$ where $k$ is a field, and let $I = (x^2, xy^n, y^{n-1})$. Then $End_R(R/I) = Hom_R(R/I,R/I) \cong Hom_{R/I} (R/I,R/I) \cong R/I$. But $R/I$ is a local ring since $\sqrt{I} = (x,y)$ which is a maximal ideal in $R$.

You may also want to take a look at Section 2 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2912 by Yi Zhang. It discusses indecomposibility of a module in terms of a presentation matrix of the module.